# SSAS -> How do you hide an attribute that is used in a hierarchy? (without using perspectives)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssas

I have some attributes that I am using to build hierarchies....(go figure).....after these attributes have been included in the hierarchy due to the change that I have made in their key columns they are no longer of use to an end user.  If that doesn't make sense you probably don't know the answer to this question.  (basically it splices the data by key columns included)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to dimension tab, right click on your attribute.  Set the attributehierarchyvisible to false.  This will stop your attribute from being visible to your enduser and it will not be seen in the cubebrowser either.

Comment: but if your dimension be used for a set, and the related set also be not shown any more.

Answer (score 0):

go to the attribute properties and there make AttributeHierarchyVisible to false. this will hide the attribute but you can still use it in defining hierarchy. but by any chance if you want get rid of an attribute, if you want to stop using an attribute in hierarrchy and in MDX query,then make AttributeHierarchyEnablr to False.